# How shrink a frame when the bottom frames inside are blank.?

Tags: jasper-reports, frame, shrink

[image: Two frames inside a main frame where each row is also a frame with two textfields]

So im trying shrink the right frame when the last two inside frames containing the
text fields(red boxes) are blank. The left and right main frames are also inside a frame. But even if only have 4 rows i always get the unused space in the report.

```
<detail>
    <band height="11" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}>1]]></printWhenExpression>
    </band>
    <band height="71" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="71" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="603f6666-1471-4d16-b0aa-bde352f18b8e">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="Default" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="301" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a12bdb49-abd3-4ecf-83db-033e5846174d"/>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="300" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="ec17f3b3-e6e1-4f57-89e1-3499e4aa63cb">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!(EXACT(continitions]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="10" uuid="96082d63-b65e-4461-951d-6f6532ca9fe0">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Morada"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="58" y="0" width="218" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="227f2a1f-3fc6-4fbf-a680-6d4ec4bbf86b"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(condditions]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="300" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="115c7def-a074-4164-8738-649cecaa095a">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[conditions]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="10" uuid="d46cb243-e8e7-4775-9abb-c8600e44f884">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["field_label"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="" x="58" y="0" width="218" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c9f0f6dc-9fc3-49bd-ac4c-7de41ac07633"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[conditions]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="10" width="300" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="016e4775-e417-4f5c-a4de-b0be970e9d3a">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="10" uuid="e4e78c67-a0c0-4d01-9942-3429ce402bc5">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$(field)]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="58" y="0" width="218" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="6b3ac9a8-28a5-413e-9348-e9625f94c235">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="300" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7f7b2531-9450-4a9f-b311-625df5ccae4f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c5a3d310-c74f-4546-97b0-18aa4de9a45a">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["field"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="58" y="0" width="218" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="649b1963-912c-4902-8052-1320e32e67ab">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="301" y="0" width="244" height="70" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c1a1530c-2fca-43d8-a238-f48f3290da29">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="40" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a96e6e9f-e02f-4e9b-a900-2e55a33df0f3">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condition)))]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="edb4759b-cf68-4367-8bc4-7e07364ae3c5">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["field_label"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="48766f62-03de-407a-a771-6e82e5a4c7ff">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="10" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="acbe8ba0-af8d-4e1a-93a8-7305a02839a6">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condition)))]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" uuid="d14807d2-aa00-421f-9dab-7cce0adf758a">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" uuid="63e62a4d-9dca-4dca-85f5-515a4ee18d0b">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{locationscope_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="cc62c22d-cc19-4461-ba53-74f4ba733322">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condition})))]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" uuid="6ce16cc5-2a18-4b3d-a7f7-17979a0a111b">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" uuid="cc7b895b-2e4f-4118-830f-1bde2e181be6">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{scope_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4c9ae6a0-6534-4952-be6c-7a18d8351a3c">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condition})))]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" uuid="1c8aedb1-020b-4d7f-aea2-93b0557b2c23">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["label"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" uuid="c7ae3de9-2f2d-4178-85b2-bf2091766558">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8f058c9f-27d5-4f0f-8eac-32a58fa7ad06">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condition})]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" uuid="ba3f46e3-c823-4815-a74d-7a4caa77828f">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" uuid="75cce569-0fc5-425b-a9fc-9a42516a4305">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="50" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="18fad1eb-f42f-4876-be03-40aac2765875">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condition}]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" uuid="2e21f092-a95f-42b1-897e-50af56985554">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" uuid="a9fe6852-4253-4fb9-a089-d007459655dd">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="244" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c102458f-d273-4611-a851-ed8e83adfead">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{condntion})]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" uuid="80dcd916-f4c8-434d-a833-e864f64ddae5">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["field_label"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="144" height="10" uuid="5676615c-3ae5-41c6-8cf1-dbdef5cc3a99">
                            <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </frame>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Stretch instead, do not try to shrink, if you like an answer you need to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jasper reports you can **not shrink** elements, instead you need to **stretch** them when needed.

In your case this means that your frames in report needs to be at the minimum size you need, then if there is more content in them you stretch it.

For example, your first frame

```
<frame>
   <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="71" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="603f6666-1471-4d16-b0aa-bde352f18b8e">
......
```

it will always have a minimum height of 71, if it it needs to be smaller (when some components are not displayed) you need to reduce this value to for example 10.

To explain this behavior, I will attach a small example, with a frame (that has a border) that contains 2 static text fields and the second one will display based on a parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="53801704-697f-43ac-aed6-9e952be4ab7f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="ShowText2" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[true]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="96" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="0" y="0" width="545" height="30" uuid="6ca5ba0c-b9c0-4ae9-be7f-e7a372593e94"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7291cb69-0d98-4ce2-8031-60b5c6df4ebb"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Static text 1]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7df247c0-2c72-4413-83f5-3d4d3aec258c">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowText2}]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Static text 2]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

### Output

**Not displaying second text field**

[image: not stretched]

**Displaying second text field**

[image: stretched]

> The key concept is that the frame has `height="30"` which is the not stretched value (minimum value) and instead it gets stretched to `height="60"` if the second text field is displayed.

Note: I'm using `stretchType="ElementGroupHeight"` since `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"` is deprecated.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I need to try this with more time. Ill be back shortly.

Comment: That codes give an error on the jasper studio:
Element reaches outside frame height: y=30, height=30, available height=30

Comment: @Maxrunner Copy past this code gives  error? Which version are you using, as you can see in screen shot it works on mine

Comment: Yes im using the jasper studio 5.6.2, but the jasper server is 6.4.2. I will try to run the report on the server directly.

Comment: @Maxrunner Yes you need version >6.0 to use this + the indicated stretchType, install newer version of jasper soft studio.

Comment: Since the server is the 6.4.2 what version of the studio should i download?

Comment: @Maxrunner I would download latest, you can set versione to save to in Studio

Comment: Hi, im having problems installing the latest versions on my linux distro. The UI is not working prorperly...

Comment: Just tried directly with the server and it works. Thanks